# Ansible use encrypted variables in other variables

Tags: mysql, encryption, ansible

I'm building several playbooks that can perform various maintenance tasks. For this they need MySQL login accounts. There are several db servers so I've created a variable that holds all the info. Example to illustrate things:

```
./vars/main.yml

  # 'secret' variables
  host1url: some_url
  host1user: user
  host1pass: pass
  host2url: some_url
  host2user: user
  host2pass: pass


  # array of db hosting info
  dbhosts:
    - name: host1
      host: {{ host1url }}
      user: {{ host1user }}
      pass: {{ host1pass }}
    - name: host2
      host: {{ host2url }}
      user: {{ host2user }}
      pass: {{ host2pass }}

./roles/the_role/tasks/main.yml
    - name: create script to perform task
      template:
        src=do_something.sh
        dest=do_something_{{ item.name }}.sh
      with_items:
        dbhosts

    - name: perform task
      command: do_something_{{ item.name }}.sh
      with_items:
        dbhosts
```

This works, but I'd like to move the 'secret' variables to a different file so I can:

- add in a different set of users based on a specific playbook or situation
- make the file encrypted for use with Ansible Vault

How can I leave the dbhosts structure in the main.yml file for reference AND move the 'secret' variables to a different file?

All I can find is info on how to add a file with variables in a task during runtime, but shouldn't it be loaded before the variable 'dbhosts' is loaded so the expansion of the variables in the dbhosts is going to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a blog post here: http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/167-ansible-real-life-good-practices

I believe this is what you are looking for:

> What we like about Ansible is the readability, and encryption has a
>   way of making things, well, less readable…
>
> `ansible-vault` command will
>   encrypt or decrypt the whole var file, you can not encrypt just the
>   value of a variable. The solution is simple enough: create a second
>   var file, just for the sensitive data. But this raises another issue:
>   your variables are now spread over multiple files, and some of them
>   encrypted. This can get messy. For instance, if you define a
>   dictionary of variables and only one of them is sensitive, you have to
>   encrypt the whole dictionary.
>
> Leaf encryption was (is) a feature request, but in the meantime, there
>   is an elegant way of keeping it both readable and secure: nested
>   variables.
>
> For every sensitive variable, you create a prefixed double that goes
>   in an encrypted file.

```
# var_file
db_password: {{ vaulted_db_passord }}
# and for a dctionnary
aws: 
  - "access_key_id='abcdefgh'"
  - "secret_access_key='{{ vaulted_aws_secret_access_key }}'"
```

---

```
# vault_file
vaulted_db_passord: a_super_secret
vaulted_aws_secret_access_key: the_aws_secret
```

> That way, you can manipulate all your vars like before, knowing the
>   vaulted version stays encrypted. You can even solve the problem of
>   having someone responsible for the encrypted file and the rest of the
>   team never seeing its content but still being able to manage var files
>   as they need.